# Called to undefined function in Laravel while reusing code from other project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this blade.php which should generate a menu:

```
<ul class="header-nav">
    @foreach(config('menu.horizontal') as $menu)
        <li class="{{set_active($menu['active'],'active')}}  @if(isset($menu['children'])) has-child @endif">
            <a href="{{$menu['link']}}" @if(isset($menu['children'])) data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" @endif><i class="{{$menu['icon']}}"></i> {{$menu['title']}}</a>
            @if(isset($menu['children']))
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    @foreach($menu['children'] as $child)
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{$child['link']}}">{{$child['title']}}</a>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

with this array:

```
return[
    'horizontal' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Dashboard',
            'link'  => '/admin',
            'active' => 'admin',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-dashboard',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Settings',
            'link'  => '/admin/settings',
            'active' => 'admin/settings*',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-cogs',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Users',
            'link'  => '#',
            'active' => 'admin/users*',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-user',
            'children' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'All Users',
                    'link'  => '/admin/users',
                    'active' => 'admin/users',
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'User Profile',
                    'link'  => '/admin/users/1',
                    'active' => 'admin/users/*',
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ]
];
```

However I get this error:

```
ErrorException in 23bb0e870ad0fbd7e21a6ce757b7bc9560d31591.php line 3:
Call to undefined function set_active() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\resources\views\admin\layouts\partials\nav\menu-horizontal.blade.php)
```

I don't get this error in the application that I copied it from. I checked out if set_active() exists and it does:

```
<?php

use App\Space\Settings\Setting;

function set_active($path, $active = 'active') {

    return call_user_func_array('Request::is', (array)$path) ? $active : '';

}...
```

It is also exactly where it is in my old project. Why won't it work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear `view` , `cache` and generate new key and rerun your program.

And provide `755` or `777` to storage folder

Commands are

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan key:generate
```

Also run

```
composer update
```

Comment: you can easily try this, If works its great, No harm to your project, its homeopathic :)